# Why did CGCC get so many views on November 5th?

Tags: discussion

According to the [site analytics tool](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) (for those who have access to it), we got a huge spike in views on November 5th.

[image]

(where green is new visitors, blue is total visits and orange is total page views)

In fact, this is higher than any other period since traffic started being recorded (sometime in Feb 2018) and it pretty much immediately subsides into normal levels by the next day. This spike was not accompanied by more posts, nor more votes, nor do any of the questions posted around that time have any more views than normal.

Does anyone know whether a post was linked somewhere or some other reason that might account for these ~10,000 extra new viewers?

Comment: Remember, remember, the fifth of November.

Comment: @Geobits I doubt it, since it was not related to CGCC.

Comment: For the record, [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/195348/66833) was the only (still Open) challenge posted on Nov 5

Comment: Perhaps A program that save all the data of the site

Comment: @RosLuP I'd expect that wouldn't also increase the total individual viewers and new users, just the page views

Comment: stress test ? something for proof the site is ok for one increase data?